# redux-auth-wrapper used with redux-persist loads login at first

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux

I am using `redux-auth-wrapper` to handle my authenticated routing needs.  It works pretty well and is easy enough to use.  However, when using it along with `redux-persist` it takes a moment to actually get the persisted authenticated user to persist in the store because of how `redux-persist` works with hydration.

So while the store is not 100% up-to-date when the page loads, I initially see the login route.  Once `redux-persist` does it's thing and hydrates the user's state, I can then see the actual authenticated route.

Is there any way around this?  I'm not entirely sure what to do to avoid this flash of login route.

*As a side note, this is a universal react app and I see this behaviour on both server and client.*

**Edit**: Here is routes.js.  Nothing crazy goin' on I don't think.  The customer/admin routes are two separate types of users, and just check that they are authenticated or not for their respective routes.

```
import Home from '../components/home/Home'
import Category from '../components/Category'
import Product from '../components/product/Product'
import Cart from '../components/cart/Cart'
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound'

import CustomerLogin from '../components/customer/CustomerLogin'
import CustomerLogout from '../components/customer/CustomerLogout'
import Customer from '../components/customer/Customer'

import AdminLogin from '../components/admin/AdminLogin'
import Admin from '../components/admin/Admin'

import GeneralLoader from '../components/GeneralLoader'

import { connectedRouterRedirect } from 'redux-auth-wrapper/history4/redirect'
import locationHelperBuilder from 'redux-auth-wrapper/history4/locationHelper'
const locationHelper = locationHelperBuilder({})

const adminIsAuthenticated = connectedRouterRedirect({
    // The url to redirect user to if they fail
    redirectPath: '/admin/login',

    // Determine if the user is authenticated or not
    authenticatedSelector: state => {
        // console.log(state.user, state.user !== null)
        return state.user.admin !== null
    },

    // Component to display while state is being persisted
    AuthenticatingComponent: GeneralLoader,

    // State persistance check (will take a second or so while redux-persist rehydrates)
    authenticatingSelector: state => !state.persist,

    // A nice display name for this check
    wrapperDisplayName: 'adminIsAuthenticated'
})

const adminIsNotAuthenticated = connectedRouterRedirect({
    // This sends the user either to the query param route if we have one, or to the landing page if none is specified and the user is already logged in
    redirectPath: (state, ownProps) => {
        return locationHelper.getRedirectQueryParam(ownProps) && locationHelper.getRedirectQueryParam(ownProps) !== '/admin/logout' ? locationHelper.getRedirectQueryParam(ownProps) : '/admin' 
    },

    // This prevents us from adding the query parameter when we send the user away from the login page
    allowRedirectBack: false,

    // Determine if the user is authenticated or not
    authenticatedSelector: state => {
        // console.log(state.user, state.user !== null)
        return state.user.admin !== null
    },

    // A nice display name for this check
    wrapperDisplayName: 'adminIsNotAuthenticated'
})

const customerIsAuthenticated = connectedRouterRedirect({
    redirectPath: '/customer/login',
    authenticatedSelector: state => {
        // console.log('customerIsAuthenticated:', state.user.customer !== null)
        return state.user.customer !== null
    },
    AuthenticatingComponent: GeneralLoader,
    authenticatingSelector: state => !state.persist,
    wrapperDisplayName: 'CustomerIsAuthenticated'
})

const customerIsNotAuthenticated = connectedRouterRedirect({
    redirectPath: (state, ownProps) => {
        return locationHelper.getRedirectQueryParam(ownProps) && locationHelper.getRedirectQueryParam(ownProps) !== '/customer/logout' ? locationHelper.getRedirectQueryParam(ownProps) : '/customer' 
    },
    allowRedirectBack: false,
    authenticatedSelector: state => {
        // console.log('customerIsNotAuthenticated:', state.user.customer === null)
        return state.user.customer === null
    },
    wrapperDisplayName: 'CustomerIsNotAuthenticated'
})

export default [
    {
        path: "/",
        exact: true,
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: "/category/:permalink",
        component: Category
    },
    {
        path: "/:category/product/:permalink",
        component: Product
    },
    {
        path: "/cart",
        component: Cart
    },
    {
        path: "/customer/login",
        component: customerIsNotAuthenticated(CustomerLogin)
    },
    {
        path: "/customer/logout",
        component: customerIsAuthenticated(CustomerLogout)
    },
    {
        path: "/customer",
        component: customerIsAuthenticated(Customer)
    },
    {
        path: "/admin/login",
        component: adminIsNotAuthenticated(AdminLogin)
    },
    {
        path: "/admin",
        component: adminIsAuthenticated(Admin)
    },
    {
        component: NotFound
    }
]
```

**relevant store.js**

```
persistStore(store, {
    whitelist: ['cart', 'user']
}, () => {

    // Once store has persisted, let the app know about it
    store.dispatch(setPersisted())
})
```

Since posting this question, I have come to a bit of a compromise/solution.

When the user loads a page such as `/customer` the store will initially have a blank user. By "loads" I mean loads it directly in the browser (not a redirect within the app).  The store has a special `persisted` property that will tell the app when the store is completed hydrated.  This property is NOT persisted across page loads and whatnot so it will be false when the app first loads and true when `redux-persist` has done the hydration.

Once the store has hydrated, the auth routing will do it's thing and direct the user as necessary if logged in.  The result of this process is kinda like when you visit an email website or whatever, where the app checks to see if you're logged in or not and you see a loading screen.

Is it the "best" way to get the `redux-auth-wrapper` and `redux-persist` packages to work together?  Not sure.

Comment: Code snippets would help us understand better your problem

Comment: Done.  Sorry I wasn't sure entirely what to include initially.  I have also worked out a pretty decent solution.  If you have criticism I am more than welcome to it :)